# RESTful API update members of group

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

I have two resources: `Group` and `Item`. Each `Item` belong to a specific `Group` and has a `status` field. I want to be able to update the status for each `Item` in a `Group` to `inactive` in a single API call. This is the only status change I want-- I won't want to change it to `active` or anything like that.

What's a RESTful way of doing this? I know having verbs in the url is frowned up, so `/api/groups/<group_id>/deactivate-items` would not be good. Would `PATCH /api/groups/<group_id>/items` with a payload of `status='inactive'` be appropriate in REST?

Answer (score 1):

> What's a RESTful way of doing this?

Think about how you would do it with a web site.

You would probably fetch some page that describes the group; somewhere on that page would be some semantic hint saying "to make all of the members of the group inactive, submit this form.  If the form were submitted, then your back end would be responsible for doing the actual work, and you would send back a page describing what just happened, with links to other interesting things to do.

Because browsers understand HTTP and HTML, all of this could be done using whatever identifiers the server happens to provide.  The server could change the action of the form freely, because the browser just executes the form processing as described in the HTML standard, and uses the target-uri described by the form meta data.

Since the identifier can be anything, you can take advantage of an interesting property - unsafe request methods (including PUT, POST, DELETE) [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) locally cached resources when successful.  So one interesting possibility would be to submit the form data back to `/api/groups/<group_id>` and invalidate any earlier copies of that page.

> Would PATCH /api/groups/<group_id>/items with a payload of status='inactive' be appropriate in REST?

Maybe - it depends on what `/api/groups/<group_id>/items` is.

A key point to keep in mind with REST is that your resource model is not your domain model is not your data model.  Resources support the protocols we want to expose to the client.

For the long form of this, see [Jim Webber's 2011 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response and link. I'll have to watch that in a bit. In terms of caching etc. I'm not doing any of that-- `Items`, `Groups` and their attributes are all stored in a database. I haven't setup the endpoints yet, but I was thinking of having `/api/groups/<group_id>/items` return a list of `Items` for a given group.